# Ada file operation: instantiation and exception

Tags: file, exception, ada

I'm learning Ada and I need some clarifications on file operations. I have just one type: float and I have to create 2 files that will store float values (with append operation). So I'm instantiating a package for the type float and I then declare 2 file variables X_File and Y_File. Then I put exceptions in case the files don't already exist.

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO;
WITH Ada.Sequential_IO;

PROCEDURE TestWrite6 IS
   PACKAGE Seq_Float_IO IS NEW Ada.Sequential_IO (Element_Type => Float);
   X_File : Seq_Float_IO.File_Type;
   Y_File : Seq_Float_IO.File_Type;


BEGIN

 Seq_Float_IO.Open (File => X_File, Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Append_File, 
 Name => "xvalues.dat");
 exception
 when Seq_Float_IO.Name_Error =>
  Seq_Float_IO.Create (File => X_File, Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Out_File, 
  Name =>  "xvalues.dat");

 Seq_Float_IO.Open (File => Y_File, Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Append_File, 
 Name => "yvalues.dat");
 exception
 when Seq_Float_IO.Name_Error =>
  Seq_Float_IO.Create (File => Y_File, Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Out_File, 
  Name => "yvalues.dat");

END TestWrite6;
```

I have two separate exceptions for each file xvalues.dat and yvalues.dat . Now on compiling, I get the error message:

```
16.
17.    Seq_Float_IO.Open (File => Y_File, Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Append_File, Name => "xvalues.dat");
18.    exception
       |
    >>> exception handler not permitted here

19.    when Seq_Float_IO.Name_Error =>
```

It seems that I can just have 1 exception for the xvalues.dat and not a second one for yvalues.dat. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot...

---

Some modifications: write a general procedure to open and append values in a file:

```
WITH Ada.Sequential_IO;
WITH Ada.Float_Text_IO;

PROCEDURE TEST is

package Seq_Float_IO is new Ada.Sequential_IO (Element_Type => Float);
X_File : Seq_Float_IO.File_Type;


procedure Open_Data(File : in out Seq_Float_IO.File_Type; 
Name : in String) is

BEGIN

   begin
      Seq_Float_IO.Open (
         File => File,
         Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Append_File,
         Name =>  );
    exception
      when Seq_Float_IO.Name_Error =>
         Seq_Float_IO.Create (
           File => File,
           Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Out_File,
           Name =>  );
   end;

END Open_Data;


x        : CONSTANT Float := 2.0;


BEGIN --main program
   Open_Data(X_File, "xvalues.dat");
   Seq_Float_IO.Write(File => X_File,Item => x);

   Seq_Float_IO.Close(File => X_File);
END TEST;
```

In procedure Open_Data. I left the 2 fields for Name =>  blank as I don't know what to put in there.

And I also put File => File...this doesn't seem ok!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A given [sequence of statements](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-5-1.html) can only have one set of [exception handlers](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-11-2.html). One approach is to wrap each handled sequence of statements in its own [block](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-5-6.html), as shown below. Noting the common statements in each block, consider writing a short subprogram that can open or create a file by name and handle any exceptions that arise.

```
with Ada.Sequential_IO;

procedure TestWrite6 is
   package Seq_Float_IO is new Ada.Sequential_IO (Element_Type => Float);
   X_File : Seq_Float_IO.File_Type;
   Y_File : Seq_Float_IO.File_Type;

begin
   begin
      Seq_Float_IO.Open (
         File => X_File,
         Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Append_File,
         Name => "xvalues.dat");
   exception
      when Seq_Float_IO.Name_Error =>
         Seq_Float_IO.Create (
            File => X_File,
            Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Out_File,
            Name =>  "xvalues.dat");
   end;
   begin
      Seq_Float_IO.Open (
         File => Y_File,
         Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Append_File, 
         Name => "yvalues.dat");
   exception
      when Seq_Float_IO.Name_Error =>
         Seq_Float_IO.Create (
            File => Y_File,
            Mode => Seq_Float_IO.Out_File, 
            Name => "yvalues.dat");
   end;
end TestWrite6;
```

Comment: Yes I shall also investigate how to create a suitable subprogram or procedure.

Comment: Excellent! BTW, `subprogram` is an Ada term for either a function or procedure. Because `File_Type` is limited private, a procedure will be more straightforward. For example, `procedure Open_Data(File : in out Seq_Float_IO.File_Type; Name : in String) is ...`

Comment: Thanks. See the code that I made (at the bottom of my post). It doesn't compile. It would be very kind of you if you would shed some light.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: For clarity, I've responded in a separate answer.